# ModelForm not creating a new entry in Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to get my form to save the responses to the database however a new entry isn't being created in the database when I try to check via the admin section. When I hit the next button the page reloads like it's supposed to and no errors pop up. I deleted the db.sqlite3 file and re-ran the migrations but it still didn't seem to work. The other forms are saving the data to the database. The issue is only with this form.

Can you tell me what changes I should make?

Thanks in advance

**views.py**

```
def qone(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        global starttime
        starttime = my_timer()
        form.save()
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = Question1Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            global endtime
            endtime = my_timer()
            global timespent1
            timespent1 = "{0} seconds".format(endtime - starttime)
            form.save(commit=True)
    else:
        form = Question1Form()

    form = Question1Form()
    return render(request,'question1.html',{'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Responses(models.Model):
question1 = models.TextField()
question2 = models.TextField()
question3 = models.TextField()
timespent1 = models.TimeField(null=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Question1Form(forms.ModelForm):
question1 = forms.CharField()
timespent1 = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class Meta:
    model = Responses
    fields = ('question1','timespent1')
```

**html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class="container">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="Submit" name="" value="Next">

  </form>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Not related, but you must not under any circumstances use global variables in a Django app.

Comment: Hi. I did that because I was getting variable errors for 'endtime' and 'starttime'

Comment: That's not my point. You should not attempt to define variables that persist across multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Errors don't show up because you redefine the form before rendering. Don't do that; remove that penultimate line.